# MVC Razor - Is it possible to render a section within a partial?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I've tried splitting up html code by creating partials, my problem was when I use a @Html.Partial, all of a sudden my section stops working.

**Error:**

> The file "~/Views/Shared/_filePartial.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method

So if it can not be requested directly, how can it be requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot put a section in a partial.  Sections must be direct children of their layouts.  You can place a partial within a section, or you can have a partial within a layout, but not the other way around.

Sections can also be nested, with a RenderSection within a Section, but only if that section is also within a nested layout (ie a layout's layout is set to a parent layout).

The real issue is that the difference between a Partial and a View is that a Partial has no layout, so when you render a view as a partial, the layout does not get rendered even if one is specified.  So without a layout, a section makes no sense.